# If $q$ is a prime divisor of $m^m-1$ then $q\not\equiv$ 1 (mod $m$)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How do I show: if $q$ is a prime divisor of $m^m-1$ then $q\not\equiv 1$ (mod $m$)? ($m \geq 3$)

Comment: What about $m=4, q=5$?

Comment: Is $m$ prime?   Do you know what $m^m \mod m$ is in that case ?

Comment: $m$ is any positive integer greater than 3. This was stated in a textbook (Niven - An Introduction to Number Theory p.108 #36), but I'm guessing it's not true

Comment: Problem 36 (ii) says: Let $q$ be any prime divisor of $m^m-1$, so that $q\not\equiv 1$ (mod $m$).. (and we only assumed $m\geq 3$ in the earlier part)

Answer (score 2):

You are misreading the text.  The entire exercise is written assuming that all prime divisors of $m^m-1$ are **not** congruent to $1\pmod m$, for the express purpose of deriving a contradiction and thereby establishing the existence of at least one prime divisor which is congruent to $1\pmod m$.  There is nothing to prove because it is an assumption.  In a way, your question is claiming the exact opposite of the overall point of the exercise :).

Comment: I just realized this too. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

That's not true though: Take $q=3$ and $m=2$. Then $m^m-1 = 2^2-1 = 3 =q$.

RE your comment take $q=5, m=4$.

In fact, something closer to the OPPOSITE is true: suppose $q$ is a prime and let $m =q-1$ so $m$ and $q$ satisfying $q \equiv_m 1$. Then $m = q-1$ so $m^m \equiv_q 1$, which implies $q$ is a prime divisor of $m^m-1$.

Comment: I forgot to add the condition $m\geq 3$

Comment: See the edit....